# Google api requests async methods fails silently but sync methods work in asp.net web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, google-api

Every time I try to use one of the async methods to execute a google api's request, it fails silently only in a asp.net web service, it fails silently, no exceptions, only this when testing in localhost:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. 
The document tree is shown below.

<TaskOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/>
```

If I change the method to the sync version all works without a problem.

For example, see my comments here:

```
    private async Task<XmlDocument> GetListAsync()
    {
        LogInfo("Descargando lista de juntas");

        try
        {
            if (_DriveService == null)
                throw new ArgumentNtullException("service");
            LogInfo("DriveService no es null");

            var request = _DriveService.Files.List();
            request.Q = $"name = '{_ListName}' and trashed = false";
            request.Fields = "files(id,parents)";
            LogInfo("Preparado request para descargar lista de juntas: {0}", request.Q);

            var result = request.Execute();//<-- this works 
            //var result = await request.ExecuteAsync(); <-- this fails silently
            LogInfo("Request para lista juntas terminado con número de resultados: {0}", result.Files.Count);
```

You can seethat after the `request.Execute` lines there are a log. If I used the async version that log is never written, also the line is never reached if I put a breakpoint there. If I use the sync version all work as it should.

I've tried it with `Files.List`'s `ExecuteAsync` and `Files.Get`'s `DownloadAsync` with same result, so I suppose it'll happen the same with other requests.

Some ideas of why is this happening?

PS:
I've just made a clean asp.net project. Added the service account key, added the minimum code to reproduce it, and same results. I think I should open an issue at github about this.

Comment: The await is never waiting so you move past the LogInfo before any log messages are received and no log messages are saved.

Comment: I've edited the cuestión. The await should wait, thats the thing, i've used the same code in desktop and in xamarin without a problem.

Comment: Then the code didn't update when you may changes.  Often this happens if you are using an older executable.  look at bin folder and check dates of the executable in both the bin and debug folder.  Often one gets compiled and the other doesn't.  Then you use older executable.  When code works in one application and not in the other it is not the code.

Comment: I thought maybe in asp.net something would change so the code won't work. Anyway, I've deleted `obj` and `bin` folders and clean, recompile the solution and F5 again. Still the same behaviour, async version don't work, sync version work.